# How to do Alignment setting of table within a table?

Tags: html

I have to create a simple table within a table. i am using following html code for making as simple page. please copy and paste it to file for understand the problem correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<BODY>
<table border=1>
  <tr>    
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>thid entry should be on top</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>why this comes in middle</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>entry1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>entry2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>entry3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>entry4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>entry5</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The main problem is in my right side part of table I have some searched information, and left side some refine search panel. so when my page comes, my refine search window comes exact middle. i want my left part of table is to aligned on table, where my  start.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: nested tables ... do you absolutely need it?

Comment: Yes, I have designed my web page in this way. that on one side I am giving some static box, and right side dynamic content. so if my dynamic content is showing 20 rows. my static box went down side. it looks very strange, is there any way to instruct it start from the top and not depend on another <td> content. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valign="top" in the correct column would be a simple solution to your prob.

like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <BODY>

        <table border=1>
            <tr>   
                <td valign="top">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>thid entry should be on top</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>why this comes in middle</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>entry1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>entry2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>entry3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>entry4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>entry5</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**edit:**
style="vertical-align:top;" if you use css